# kineticjs animate rotation onclick multiple times

Tags: kineticjs

I gettin stuck on some Kinetic.js thing. I want to rotate the shapes 45 degrees every time you click or tap, but now its only one time. I'm using tween to animated the rotation.

An Example here: [jsfiddle](http://tinyurl.com/orjcbd2)

Can someone help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the tween when you click on a node

```
layer.on('click tap', function(evt) {
  evt.targetNode.tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: evt.targetNode,
    duration: 0.3,
    rotationDeg: evt.targetNode.rotation()+45,
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseOut
  });
  evt.targetNode.tween.play();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JUu2Q/6/

Comment: This works, but it's better to create the tween outside the tap event handler and then tween.play() inside the tap event.  Otherwise you're creating a new tween with every tap ;)